# When to use set and add methods in list

Tags: java

`cutDeck()` does the last step of shuffling -- cutting the deck. This should move the first `cutLocation` number of cards ("first" meaning at the lowest index) from cards and add them to the back of the List. Make certain that you add cards in the same (relative) order that they were originally stored.

```
public List<PlayingCard> cutDeck(int cutLocation) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cutLocation; i++) {
        cards.add(cards.get(i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cutLocation; i++) {
        cards.remove(cards.get(i));
    }
    return cards;
}
```

This is the error message i am getting

> cutDeck(133) did not correctly cut when cards had 208 cards. At index 0 expected 5H but was 3C expected:<[5H]> but was:<[3C]>

I can't see how I am doing something wrong, is it my logic should I be using the `cards.set()` instead of `cards.add()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your removal is wrong. Imagine `cards` has five cards in it and we're splitting it after the first two cards.

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

After your first loop terminates, you get:

```
1 2 3 4 5 1 2
```

Now, your second loop starts and removes the first card at `i = 0`, which is `1`

```
2 3 4 5 1 2
```

Now, your second loop removes the first card at `i = 1`, which is `3`, and NOT `2`!

This is where your mistake is. You could simplify the whole logic to a single for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cutLocation; i++) {
    cards.add(cards.remove(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you removed the first card in your second `for` loop all your cards will have been shifted to the front by one position. But your loop variable `i` is still increasing and you use it in your `cards.get(i)` call. This means that when you are in the second iteration of your loop you will call `cards.get(1)`, but this would be the original third card to remove. After that you try to remove the next card with `cards.get(2)`, but it would delete the original fifth card and so on.

You might want to use `cards.removeAt(0)` to (always) remove the card at the beginning until you reached the limit `cutLocation`.